# C# - Determining if Value is In byte value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, bit

I'm working on a web page that ties into an existing database that I cannot change :(. The page has a checkbox list. The list has four checkboxes. The values of the checkboxes are 1, 2, 3, and 4. Someone before me decided to store the selected combination of these as a nullable `tinyint` in the database. In my C# code, that `tinyint` becomes a `short?`.

To store the selected values in the database, there is code like the following in the controller:

```
var selectedValues = new List<short>();
foreach (string v in model.ValueList)
{
  short t = -1;
  if (Int16.TryParse(v, out t))
    selectedValues.Add(t);
}
model.SelectedValues = (short)(selectedValues .Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x | 1 << (y - 1)));
```

This is how the value gets persisted. I see values like 5, 11, etc. However, the checkboxes in the list are NOT getting re-populated. I see the following code in my MVC view.

```
@foreach (var v in Model.ValueList)
{
  var isChecked = false;
  if (Model.SelectedValues.HasValue)
  {
    // TODO. use bit operation to determine if the checkbox was 
    // selected
  }

  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ValueList" />
    @v.Text
  </label>
}
```

That `todo` block is throwing me for a loop. I'm not sure how to properly use a bitwise operation to determine if a checkbox should be checked or not. How in the world can I do that? (can I even do it?)

Comment: why do you feel you need to use bitwise when all you need to do is check for the the following for example `checkedListBox1_ItemCheck` and you can also do this in a foreach loop as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would create a view model to represent the selected values i.e.

```
public class Selection
{
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }                
    public bool Checked { get; set; }           
}
```

Add a property to your current model to represent the checkbox list i.e.

```
public class AModel
{
    public AModel()
    {
        CheckBoxList = new List<Selection>();    
    }

    public List<Selection> CheckBoxList { get; set; }

    // existing properties 

}
```

From your controller you will need to have a list of available selections to begin with. Then loop these setting the `Checked` property as follows (please note without seeing your code I have assumed the `AvailableSelections` property is a list of shorts):

```
// Build up a list of the entire checkboxes
var checkBoxList = new List<Selection>();
foreach(var shortValue in Model.`AvailableSelections`)
{
    checkBoxList.Add(new Selection { ID = shortValue, Name = shortValue.ToString()  });

}
model.CheckBoxList = checkBoxList;

// Select the values
foreach (short v in model.ValueList)
{
    var checkBox = checkBoxList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == v);
    checkBox.Checked = true;
}
```

Then in your view you could render out the checkboxes as follows, making use of the `Html.CheckBoxFor`:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxList.Count; i++)
{
     <label class="checkbox">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CheckBoxList[i].ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.CheckBoxList[i].Name)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.CheckBoxList[i].Checked)
        @Model[i].Name
    </label>

}
```

Note the for loop instead of foreach to enable model binding and the hidden fields to allow the values to be posted back to the controller

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

```
Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x | 1 << (y - 1))
```

Here's what's happening here:

1. `y - 1` converts the checkbox value `y` into a zero-indexed bit position.
2. `1 << (y-1)` produces the value 2<sup>y-1</sup>, i.e. a value where only the bit in position `y-1` is set.
3. `x | 1 << (y-1)` combines the value produced in step 2 with the overall result thus far via bitwise `OR`, which in this case is equivalent to addition since no two of the values being combined have a bit set in the same position.

So a checkbox whose value is `y` will be checked if and only if bit `y-1` in `Model.SelectedValues` is set. In other words, if and only if:

```
(Model.SelectedValues & (1 << (y - 1))) > 0
```

I wouldn't put code like this in your view, though. If it's stored in the database this way and you can't change that, then so be it, but you should be able to transform the database value into a format that you can work with more intuitively right when you load it, so you can avoid this kind of bit twiddling every time you need to access the data.